# Split selection into lines in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

In Sublime I was quite fond of the "Split selection into lines" shortcut (super+shift+l). However I cannot find an equivalent of that in PHP Storm 8, I've found a "Split into lines" function in the Edit menu but feeding it either \n or \r doesn't seem to work. Does that function exist in PS ?

Comment: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/working-with-multiple-selection-in-phpstorm-8-eap/

Comment: I am aware of multiple cursors but I meant automatically split selection into lines. If I have a 200 line selection I don't want to have to create a cursor at the end of every line.

Answer (score 15):

By default on PHPStorm 10+, you can toggle the Column Selection Mode with:

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>

Of course, you can configure any stroke you like. I like to keep the original one and add the one that matches Sublime which is <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. Here is how:

[image: How to configure column selection mode stroke in PHPStorm]

Answer (score 10):

Another option would be to use `column selection mode:`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30031481/672989

Answer (score 6):

There is a "Split Selection into Lines" action in the [Extra Actions plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8213-extra-actions).

> Compatible with: Compatible with: IntelliJ IDEA  PhpStorm  WebStorm  PyCharm  RubyMine  AppCode  CLion  GoLand  DataGrip  Rider MPS  Android Studio

Comment: No shortcuts are set by default.

You can easily set them by going to

Settings > Keymap > Plugins > Extra Actions

(credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53012594/2832282)

Comment: On macOS, there is a system shortcut assigned to CMD+Shift+L you might want to disable : see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/180065/178628

Answer (score 3):

> If I have a 200 line selection I don't want to have to create a cursor at the end of every line.

You do not have to *"create a cursor at the end of every line"* -- just create cursor on the beginning of each line (on Windows it would be <kbd>Alt+Mouse drag Down/Up</kbd>) and then just press <kbd>End</kbd> button. This is not that straightforward as separate dedicated action .. but still does the same job and pretty easy to execute.

---

**In any case:** there is no such **exact** action currently available in PhpStorm, unfortunately.

Please follow this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122181