# PyCharm: Turning selection to multiple cursors per line

Tags: pycharm

Sublime Text has this functionality where you can select text and start editing each line with a (multiple) cursor:

[image]

Is there PyCharm equivalent?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122181 for similar behaviour.

Comment: In the linked issues there is a link to third-party plugin [Extra Actions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8213), which implements desired funtionality precisely without any hacks.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin: Perfect!

Comment: `cmd` + `shift` + `L` worked for me in Atom- OSX.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This functionality was added to Pycharm in [June 2020](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122181#focus=Comments-27-4176245.0-0).

It's called "Add Carets to Ends of Selected Lines", and is bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> by default.

Comment: ⌥⇧G in Mac. [JetBrains reference link](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/guide/tips/add-carets-at-line-end/).

Answer (score 105):

Another option: with text selected, toggle column selection mode:

[image]

The default shortcut to toggle the mode is:

- Linux/Windows: `alt`-`shift`-`insert`
- Mac `cmd`-`shift`-`(numpad) *`

(or `Edit`→`Column Selection Mode`)

It's an inconvenient shortcut for Mac, as most laptops have no numpad. I remapped it to `cmd`-`shift`-`8`.

Column selection mode actually has other purposes too: it changes the default behavour when selecting text with the keyboard and mouse. Toggle it off again to return to normal selection behaviour.

Comment: In phpstorm 10, I found I can press `cmd`-`shift`, then click twice `8`. ;p

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.

Answer (score 71):

From [source](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/multicursor.html):

> To add carets, do one of the following
>
> - Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and click the `LEFT` mouse button at the location of the caret.
> - Double-click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>up arrow</kbd> or <kbd>down arrow</kbd> keys.

On OSX it seems to be enough to press down the `LEFT`-<kbd>ALT</kbd> and add new carets with mouse `LEFT CLICK`, or press down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> and paint the cursors with mouse.

Comment: In addition there's Alt + J that allows you to select the next occurrence of your selection.

Comment: Thanks. SHIFT+ALT is what I was looking for. It is not exactly what Sublime Text does (converts existing selection to multiple cursors), but close enough.

Comment: @BornToCode it seems to just be `alt` alone on Linux, for me, no shift. Additionally, many distros by default map _one_ of the `alt`s to a different keypress (`meta` or something), so try both the left and right alt keys. This can be changed, but the directions are different depending on your distro.

Comment: @BornToCode one can try `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Alt` +`LMB` (left mouse button)

Comment: @fikr4n Shift-Alt does work on PyCharm 2019.2 on linux. It used to be only Alt (as it still is in CLion, for example)

Comment: Moving the correct answer mark because of an update after 3 years.

Answer (score 23):

Hold `Alt` and drag the mouse over the desired text.

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html

Comment: out of all the answers, your answer was most simple and useful. Thanks @Vagelis

Answer (score 9):

To do this on Linux (tested on Ubuntu 16.04), do as follows:

In your editor, press `Alt` + `Windows Key` and use your mouse to place the cursor on the lines you want to have multiple cursors on.

You may also want to `allow placement of caret after the end of line` or `inside tabs`. In that case you need to change your settings:

Go to `Editor -> Generaral -> Virtual Space:`

- [x] Allow placement of caret after end of line
- [x] Allow placement of caret inside tabs

And make sure the above mentioned two settings are enabled.

Answer (score 5):

You can use plugin **[Extra Actions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8213-extra-actions)**.

You must add a combination to this action:

> Split Selection into Lines

**No shortcuts are set by default.**

You can easily set them by going to

> Settings > Keymap > Plugins > Extra Actions

[Configuring keyboard shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html#configure).

Answer (score 4):

Press SHIFT + DownArrow ( instead of mouse and drag) in pycharm for multi cursor editing

Answer (score 2):

The simple way I think is to select the text and go on pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> for Linux and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> for Mac until you reach the last match.

[PyCharm blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2014/09/feature-spotlight-multiple-selections-in-pycharm/)

Answer (score 1):

**Sublime like features for MacOS X in PyCharm:**

Select/Unselect the **next** occurrence with `Ctrl+G` / `Shift+Ctrl+G`

Select **all** occurrences at once with `Ctrl+Cmd+G`

Remove occurrences with `ESC`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `alt + shift + G` for selected lines to enable caret for them and  use `Home` and `End` buttons to go to the start or end of your line(s).

1. select your line(s).
2. press `alt + shift + G`
3. press `Home` or `End` to go to the start or the end of your line(s).

you could also use `alt + click` for selecting by clicking and `alt + J` to select same values.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+t",
    "command": "editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected",
    "when": "editorHasSelection && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly",
},
```

`ctrl+t` - as an example.

Answer (score -1):

For **macOS** users: looks like if you hold `shift` + `down` or `up` arrow keys to select with multiple cursors.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ynbH.png)